# How to specify groups while creating a region using spring data geode?

Tags: gemfire, geode, spring-data-gemfire, spring-boot-data-geode

Apache geode regions can be created on members from a specific groups as per their documentation: https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/114/tools_modules/gfsh/command-pages/create.html#topic_54B0985FEC5241CA9D26B0CE0A5EA863

How can we achieve the same for regions created using @EnableEntityDefinedRegion in an application using Spring Data Geode / Spring Boot Data Geode?

I checked @Region annotation and its type based parents, but could not figure out where groups could be set.